# Convert ZonedDateTime to LocalDateTime at time zone

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, datetime-conversion, zoneddatetime

I have an object of `ZonedDateTime` that is constructed like this

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 30), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

How can I convert it to `LocalDateTime` at time zone of Switzerland? Expected result should be `16 april 2018 13:30`.

Comment: As an aside, pass a `ZoneId` to `LocalDate.now()` too to obtain predictable results. It is never the same date everywhere on the globe.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

> How can I convert it to LocalDateTime at time zone of Switzerland?

You can convert the UTC `ZonedDateTime` into a `ZonedDateTime` with the time zone of Switzerland, but maintaining the same instant in time, and then get the `LocalDateTime` out of that, if you need to. I'd be tempted to keep it as a `ZonedDateTime` unless you need it as a `LocalDateTime` for some other reason though.

```
ZonedDateTime utcZoned = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 30), ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZoneId swissZone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich");
ZonedDateTime swissZoned = utcZoned.withZoneSameInstant(swissZone);
LocalDateTime swissLocal = swissZoned.toLocalDateTime();
```

Answer (score 27):

It helps to understand the difference between LocalDateTime and ZonedDateTime. What you really want is a `ZonedDateTime`. If you wanted to remove the timezone from the string representation, you would convert it to a `LocalDateTime`.

What you're looking for is:
`ZonedDateTime swissZonedDateTime = withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich"));`

**LocalDateTime** - this is basically a glorified string representation of a `Date` and `Time`; it is timezone agnostic, which means it does not represent any point in time on a timeline

**Instant** - this is a millisecond representation of time that has elapsed since EPOCH. This represents a specific instant in time on a timeline

**ZonedDateTime** - this also represents an instant in time on a timeline, *but* it represents it as a `Date` and `Time` with a `TimeZone`.

The code below illustrates how to use all 3.

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 10, 25, 12, 00, 00);  //October 25th at 12:00pm
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeInUTC = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")); 
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeInEST = zonedDateTimeInUTC.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")); 
    
System.out.println(localDateTime.toString()); // 2018-10-25T12:00
System.out.println(zonedDateTimeInUTC.toString()); // 2018-10-25T12:00Z[UTC]
System.out.println(zonedDateTimeInEST.toString()); // 2018-10-25T08:00-04:00[America/New_York]
```

If you were to compare the `Instant` values of both `ZonedDateTimes` from above, they would be equivalent because they both point to the same instant in time. Somewhere in Greenwich (UTC timezone), it is noon on October 25th; at the same time, in New York, it would be 8 am (America/NewYork timezone).

Answer (score 5):

Try this out. Substitute US/Central with your timezone.

```
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 30), ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println(z.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("US/Central")));
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option that seems a little more intuitive is to convert the zoned date to an instant, then use LocalDateTime.ofInstant:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 30), ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZoneId zId = ZoneId.of("US/Central");
LocalDateTime l = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(zdt.toInstant(), zId);
```

I prefer this to `withZoneSameInstant` because that solution little more opaque - you're getting a ZonedDateTime that has to be in a particular internal state (the correct time zone). Using `ofInstant` can be used on any ZonedDateTime in any time zone.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve what you want. Some of them are as follows:

1. Convert the given `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` and derive `LocalDateTime` from the `Instant`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 30), ZoneOffset.UTC);

Instant instant = zdtUtc.toInstant();

LocalDateTime ldtSwitzerland = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich"));
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/FtsR8J)

2. Use [`ZonedDateTime#withZoneSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#withZoneSameInstant-java.time.ZoneId-) to convert the given `ZonedDateTime` to a `ZonedDateTime` in the desired timezone, and then get the `LocalDateTime` from the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 30), ZoneOffset.UTC);

ZonedDateTime zdtSwitzerland = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich"));

LocalDateTime ldtSwitzerland = zdtSwitzerland.toLocalDateTime();
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Ahz43F)

3. Convert the given `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` which can be converted to a `ZonedDateTime` using [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) , and then get the `LocalDateTime` from the `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 30), ZoneOffset.UTC);

Instant instant = zdtUtc.toInstant();

ZonedDateTime zdtSwitzerland = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich"));

LocalDateTime ldtSwitzerland = zdtSwitzerland.toLocalDateTime();
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/V2efGn)

4. Use `DateTimeFormatter` to format the given `ZonedDateTime` into the Date-Time string pertaining to the desired timezone and then derive the `LocalDateTime` by parsing the obtained Date-Time string. **Note:** Use this method just for your learning purpose; you should implement the first way (topmost) in your production code.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDate.now().atTime(11, 30), ZoneOffset.UTC);

DateTimeFormatter dtfSwitzerland = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Zurich"));
String strZdtSwitzerland = dtfSwitzerland.format(zdtUtc);

LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime
        .from(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME.parse(strZdtSwitzerland, new ParsePosition(0)));
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ww94x2)

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.