# Change Date to Local time zone of the device in Java

Tags: java, android

I'm getting a value of type `Date` from the Database. Here is an example `Wed Jul 29 13:03:00 GMT +03:00 2020`

and I have the following method to convert it to string

```
public static final String VIEW_DATE_FORMAT = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm";

public static String dateToString(Date date){
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(General.VIEW_DATE_FORMAT , Locale.getDefault());
    if(date == null)
        return "";
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

My Question is how to convert the date to the Local time zone of the device the app is installed on ?
I want the date to become `Wed Jul 29 2020 16:03:00` but I'm getting `Wed Jul 29 2020 13:03:00` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you are using at least API level 26 then you should use class [`ZonedDateTime`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376242/java8-java-util-date-conversion-to-java-time-zoneddatetime) which you can then convert to a `LocalDateTime`.

To convert a `Date` object to `ZonedDateTime`, refer to [Java8 java.util.Date conversion to java.time.ZonedDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376242/java8-java-util-date-conversion-to-java-time-zoneddatetime)

To convert `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime`, refer to [Convert ZonedDateTime to LocalDateTime at time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853999/convert-zoneddatetime-to-localdatetime-at-time-zone)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public String local_time(String date)
{

    Time time = new Time();
    try {
     date=  date.replace("GMT +","GMT+");
         time.set(new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy").parse(date).getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    String timeString =  time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S  %Z %Y");
   // Log.e("Time string ",""+timeString);
   /* changing time zone */
    time.switchTimezone(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
   // Log.e("Time zone ",""+Time.getCurrentTimezone());

   
     timeString = time.format("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S  %Z %Y");
   // Log.e("New time ",""+timeString);
    return timeString;
}
```

call it like `String loc_time=local_time("Wed Jul 29 13:03:00 GMT +03:00 2020");`

remember to import android.text.format.Time : `import android.text.format.Time;`