# Parse a String to LocaDateTime in Java

Tags: java, string, datetime

Consider a String `"2022-03-23 21:06:29.4933333 +00:00"`.
How do I parse the above DateTimeOffset String to LocalDateTime in Java?

I tried with the following DateTimeFormatter but the format seems to be incorrect:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss\[.nnnnnnn\] \[+|-\]hh:mm\]");

LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, formatter)
```

Comment: Go via `ZonedDateTime` first

Comment: Do you understand that by using `LocalDateTime`, you will be discarding vital information: the offset? Your input represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. But a `LocalDateTime` cannot, by definition. You should be using `OffsetDateTime` here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, start by having the [JavDocs for `DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) at hand, this is going to really help determine which specifiers you need

The first thing to do is parse the text into a `ZonedDateTime`, `LocalDateTime` won't parse a input value with a time zone (AFAIK), you "might" be able to force it, but what's the point?

```
String text = "2022-03-23 21:06:29.4933333 +00:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS z");
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(text, formatter);
System.out.println(zdt);
```

This prints...

```
2022-03-23T21:06:29.493333300Z
```

Now you could use `ZonedDateTime#toLocalDateTime`, but this won't take into account the current time zone of the user/computer.

If you need to convert the `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDateTime`, it's best to do so in away which will translate the time (and date if required) to best represent the time within the current time zone (okay, I was confused typing it)

For example, converting the input value into my current time zone (+11 hours) would look like this...

```
ZoneId currentZone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
ZonedDateTime currentZDT = zdt.withZoneSameInstant(currentZone);
System.out.println(currentZDT);
LocalDateTime ldt = currentZDT.toLocalDateTime();
System.out.println(ldt);
```

which will print...

```
2022-03-24T08:06:29.493333300+11:00[Australia/Melbourne]
2022-03-24T08:06:29.493333300
```

This means that at 9:06pm on the 23rd March in Grinch (GMT), it was 8:06am on the 24th March where I live.

Now you can use different `ZoneId`s to convert to a `TimeZone` which is not the current computers `TimeZone`, but I'll leave that up to you to experiment with (for example, I used [Convert ZonedDateTime to LocalDateTime at time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853999/convert-zoneddatetime-to-localdatetime-at-time-zone) to base my example on)

Comment: Since the string contains an offset, `+00:00`, and no time zone like Australia/Melbourne, prefer `OffsetDateTime` over `ZonedDateTime`. Otherwise a fine answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need create custom [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

```java
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String dateString = "2022-03-23 21:06:29.4933333 +00:00";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .append(java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
                .appendLiteral(' ')
                .appendOffsetId()
                .toFormatter();

        //In case of OffSet matter, retaining the instant
        LocalDateTime localDateTimeSavePointOfTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter).withOffsetSameInstant(OffsetDateTime.now().getOffset()).toLocalDateTime();

        //In case OffSet does not matter we can skip it
        LocalDateTime localDateTimeSkipOffSet = LocalDateTime.parse(dateString, formatter);

    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, except the result isn't converted into the current systems `TimeZone`, I don't know if that's important or not, but I'm picky about date/time manipulation

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for the given input. That input includes an offset. The offset is vital information which you discard by using `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: Described two cases, when OffSet matters or not

Comment: A very fine demonstration of building a custom formatter from built-in parts (I don’t think you need `parseCaseInsensitive()`).

Comment: Agreed, in this particular case parseCaseInsensitive() is useless.