# How to convert ZonedDateTime to LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I want to convert local date and time to UTC and then back to local date and time, I could not find solutions on internet. I used below code:

```java
// get local date and time
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
// print local date time
System.out.println(localDateTime);
// get system time zone / zone id
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
// get UTC time with zone offset
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).atZone(zoneId);
System.out.println(zonedDateTime);
// now I want to convert the UTC with timezone back to local time, 
// but below code is not working  
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime());
```

#### result expected

```
local date and time = 2023-08-01T17:15:10.832796200  
zoned date and time = 2023-08-01T11:45:10.832796200+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]  
local date and time after conversion = 2023-08-01T17:15:10.832796200
```

Comment: Can you please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49853999/convert-zoneddatetime-to-localdatetime-at-time-zone

Comment: `zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime()`

Comment: below is the output (7:22, expected is 18:22)
2023-08-01T18:22:09.103796200
2023-08-01T12:52:09.103796200
2023-08-01T12:52:09.103796200+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
2023-08-01T07:22:09.103796200

Comment: I don't quite get why you would want to convert something to another thing and then convert that back to the original thing… That's creating (at least) 3 objects, though the first one and the third one are expected to be equal. Why not keep the first?

Comment: Is this just an academic exercise?  What is your use case?  This sounds like it could be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: actually my use case is:
1. Get local date and time from my local system
2. And get corresponding local date and time from any other country / city

Or if I know UTC time with Zone ID, then convert it to that zone local date and time

hope this is a valid scenario - in the above code I am converting it back to original jut to check the value is what I am looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).atZone(zoneId);`

This is suspect code. This code says:

What time is it right now *in the UTC zone*. So, here in Amsterdam it's 15:46, but if I were to run that (we're in summer time right now, amsterdam has a +2 offset), `LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)` gives me a **local** DT object with local time 13:46. It doesn't have a timezone, because.. it's local date time.

You then 'place' that time (of 13:46) in a zone. Let's say `zoneId` is Europe/Amsterdam, this code gets me a time that happened 2 hours ago. It doesn't make any sense, you would never want to write this code.

What you presumably want is:

```
LocalDateTime nowAtUtc = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime zoned = nowAtUtc.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
ZonedDateTime inAmsterdam = zoned.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));
System.out.println(inAmsterdam.toLocalDateTime());
```

the above code prints the current time as per my clock here in The Netherlands.

Of course, that *exact* snippet is pointless - why convert from A to B and right back again? Ordinarily you'd just go `LocalDateTime.now()` if you want an LDT, or if you want a ZDT, simply `ZonedDateTime.now(zoneYouAreInterestedIn);`. However, I assume you asked the question because you do a bunch of stuff in between that you elided from the question.

Comment: the answer to why convert from A to B and right back again? is to check if my code is correct. I wanted to convert UTC to  a given zoneId.
I got where I made mistake, below line helped me
ZonedDateTime zoned = nowAtUtc.atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);

thank you a lot for the clarification, it helped

Answer (score 0):

#### Just in addition to the answer by @rzwitzerloot…

Use a definite moment in time as base for coversion and zone hopping.

`java.time` has such a definite moment in time: An `Instant`

Here's some example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Asia/Calcutta");
    // get a moment in time (Unix epoch) and use it as base
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    // get the local date and time in your zone based on the instant
    LocalDateTime local = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(now, zoneId);
    System.out.println(local);
    // get the zoned date and time in UTC based on the instant
    ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    System.out.println(utc);
    // get the zoned date and time in your zone based on the instant 
    ZonedDateTime localZone = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(now, zoneId);
    System.out.println(localZone);
    // extract the local date and time from it
    LocalDateTime backToLocal = localZone.toLocalDateTime();
    // then check for equality
    if (local.equals(backToLocal)) {
        System.out.println(local + " == " + backToLocal);
    } else {
        System.err.println(local + " != " + backToLocal);
    }
}
```

Output (right now):

```
2023-08-01T20:14:39.776239
2023-08-01T14:44:39.776239Z
2023-08-01T20:14:39.776239+05:30[Asia/Calcutta]
2023-08-01T20:14:39.776239 == 2023-08-01T20:14:39.776239
```

I used a fix `ZoneId` in order to have yours in the example.

Comment: thank you a lot for this help, I now got where I made the mistake.